# Spring WebClient: How to convert a HTTP response body to String for a specific encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding, spring-webclient

I am using `WebClient` of the Spring webflux module for the first time.

The idea is to query a certain URL which gives me a CSV in `shift-jis` encoding.

```java
String content = webClient
    .method(HttpMethod.GET)
    .acceptCharset(Charset.forName("shift-jis")) 
    .uri(uri)
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, new MediaType("text", "csv"))
    .retrieve()
    .toEntity(String.class)
    .mapNotNull(HttpEntity::getBody)
    .block();
```

This works somewhat, but the `content` String looks like it is in a wrong encoding - probably UTF-8.

Alternatively, an Apache `HttpClient` version seems to work:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
String content = IOUtils.toString(
    client.execute(get).getEntity().getContent(), 
    Charset.forName("shift-jis"));
```

So I am wondering how one could interfere with the conversion happening in `toEntity`. I tried adding this to the `webClient` call:

```java
.codecs(configurer -> {
   StringDecoder decoder = StringDecoder.textPlainOnly();
   decoder.setDefaultCharset(Charset.forName("shift-jis"));
   configurer.customCodecs().registerWithDefaultConfig(decoder);
})
```

Alas, this does not seem to be picked up. Setting a breakpoint in `StringDecoder#decode` and manually overwriting the `defaultCharset` field during debugging, however, *does* help.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... Just after posting I realized: Maybe my custom `text/csv` mime type is not really interpreted as `textPlainOnly`.

And, indeed:

```java
StringDecoder decoder = StringDecoder.allMimeTypes();
```

apparently does the trick.

Leaving the question open in case my approach is awfully hacky and there are better/correct ways to tackle this issue.